# Display web browser history

Tags: objective-c, webview, browser, browser-history

I am currently in the process of developing a simple, cocoa document based web browser in Objective-C, using the webkit framework.

I want to add a window to display the browsing history.  I have created the window with a text box and all that, but I can not for the life of me figure how to display the browsing history in the textbox.

Please do not refer me to the apple developer resources online, as I have already read that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to enable the web view's built-in history with `setMaintainsBackForwardList:`, if you haven't already done so.

You can then access the browsing history with the `backForwardList` method which returns an object of the class `WebBackForwardList`.

This isn't a simple array, because it also needs to maintain a position within the history, in case the user goes back (to be able to go forward again). To display a history menu or window, you're probably most interested in the `backListCount` and `backListWithLimit:` methods. The latter returns an `NSArray` of `WebHistoryItem` objects. Those have the methods `URLString`, `title`, `icon` and `lastVisitedTimeInterval`. You can use these methods to display information about the individual history items.